# Why isn't display inline working?

Tags: html, css

I am having a really odd situation here. I have spent the last 7 hours researching why I cannot get `display: inline;` to work at all, unless it's on my main page. Nothing seems to be helping.

Here is the relevant coding.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>      
<head>
  <title>Contact Info</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="name">
    <p>*****<p>
    <a href="index.html">Go Back</a>
  </div>

  <div class="contact">
    <p>
      <span style="color:#000000">By Phone:</span>
      <a href="tel:*******">**********</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span style="color:#000000">By Email:</span> 
      <a href="mailto:****@***.ca">****@****.ca</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <span style="color:#000000">By Mail:</span> 
      <span style="color:#3300cc">***************</span>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

And here is the CSS.

```
.name {
  display: inline;
}
```

The result is the two items, (The name "****" and the "Go Back" link), appear one on top of each other. I have tried making it a list, but that had no effect. I tried making them both links, but that had no effect. `display: inline-block;` also has no effect. Nothing I do has any effect on the div class name. I tried changing the name of the div class several times no effect.

Comment: What is your desired outcome? What should be on the same line?

Comment: A name that I censored with **** and a link that says go back. the two items in the name div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is the the `<p>` tag is also a block level element. One solution would be to add a style such that a `<p>` within the `.name` div is also inline

```
.name, .name p {display: inline;}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/t0z2p9bn/

It would be better to change your html such that the stars are not contained within a `<p>` tag

```
<div class ="name">
*****
<a href="index.html">Go Back</a>
</div>
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/t0z2p9bn/1/

Comment: Thank you very much. Worked Immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1. **div**s should not be used for inline elements. Did you mean to use a **span**?
2. There is a typo - it shouldn't make a difference, but there's an unneeded space after "class" here:

`<div class ="name">`